# How to save dynamic data into CoreData?

Tags: ios, core-data

I am downloading data from server which is dynamic.

For example

```
<Latitude>...</Latitude>
<Longitude>...</Longitude>
<Images>
 <ImgUrl>...</ImgUrl>
 <ImgUrl>...</ImgUrl>
 <ImgUrl>...</ImgUrl>
 <ImgUrl>...</ImgUrl>
```

Here ImgUrl may vary, it can be 2, 3, or 4.

As, Table in CoreData is constant, with pre-defined number of rows. So, how can I achieve my aim?

The one idea in my mind was of appending all of them and save in one row, but I think there might be some other better solutions. So, help is required.

Thanks

***How can Make Database field to save it dynamically?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple one-to-many relationship between objects. One object can have many images. An image belongs to only one object.

You model this by creating two entities in XCode: one for images and one for data. You then create a relationship between them. Check the Plural checkbox for "To-Many Relationship", and don't forget to also create an inverse relationship from images back to the data object.

Comment: then how will i save it, suppose i have two array, one contain object and second array?

Comment: Sorry, did not see your comment until now, @Duaan! Will check my notification settings...
What does the second array contain? The images? Please elaborate...

Answer (score 3):

You should make two entities e.g. LocationObject and ImageObject.
Then create one to many relationship: one LocationObject to many ImageObject

Comment: then how will i save it, suppose i have two array, one contain object and second array?